# Using a Pandas Dataframe element as label text in Tkinter

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel range that I am reading as a dataframe. The aim is to use the text or numbers in dataframes cells as text in labels. Below is the code I am using,

```
df_dash_val = pd.read_excel('389FT83001 Orifice-Original.xlsm', sheet_name='GraphsSummary', usecols="A:B",nrows=25)   

var_1 = StringVar()
var_2 = StringVar()
var_3 = StringVar()

var_1.set(df_dash_val.iat[0,1])
var_2.set(df_dash_val.iat[1, 1])
var_3.set(df_dash_val.iat[2, 1])

lab_tag2 = Label(frame_dash1, textvariable=var_1, anchor=W, width=20, font='Tahoma 15', fg="black", bg='white')
```

But when I do this, no text is found in the label and when I use print(var_1) to check the value assigned to var_1, then it shows that "PY_VAR6". Can you please help? I have done the same with xlwings, but that is slower as compared to pandas. So I would like to do it with Pandas. THANKS!!!

Comment: Are you sure `df_dash_val.iat[0,1]` is a string? If you want to check the value of `var_1` you should print `var_1.get()`

Comment: I think var_1.get will only work if var_1 is a widget but this is supposed to be a variable

Comment: Have you tried it? See this [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#coupling-widget-variables) in the python doc